# ImportError: No module named cv2 after install VS2017

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-2017

Before:

- Install VS2015.
- Install opencv 3.2.0.

Now, i install VS2017 and create python project with the following code:

```
import cv2
```

When I run it, compiler show the error: "ImportError: No module named cv2"

How to update some libraries - which i installed before - as opencv, numpy,... for VS2017?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I knew the reason. Because when i installed VS2017, i also installed other version of Python. VS2017 used the wrong version (it does not have opencv library). And then i created new universal windows python project, VS2017 auto generate PythonUwpIoT (python 3.5 - i don't know and how to have it).

Comment: To update the libraries you may use `pip install`. I would suggest to take a look to [this tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html) specially steps 7-9 to test if opencv python is install, or if visual studio needs something extra...

Comment: @api55 
VS2017 does not recognize the libraries installed before.(I still keep VS 2015 not uninstall). How to use pip install to update for VS2017? 
"I would suggest to take a look to this tutorial specially steps 7-9 to test if opencv python is install, or if visual studio needs something extra..." I also did it but not success

Comment: So you opened python from the console (not visual studio) did import cv2 and also failed? or just inside vs fails?

Comment: @api55 yes. just for VS 2017

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct interpreter in Visual Studio?

Comment: @BoboDarph I don't understand what you said. Can you explain for me. Tks!

Comment: If you have different binaries in your shell and your visualstudio, then you will most likely run into your described problem. For example, when you run "pip install somepackage" in your command shell, it will end up installing that package to the python interpreter to which pip points to (most likely the one in your PYTHONPATH variable in PATH). What it will not do, however, is install that package for all available python installations. Visual Studion might be using a different python binary from a different location, and your pip install wont affect it.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-environments#managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio about managing your python env in visual studio.

Comment: Thanks @BoboDarph. I update my question